# How can I pull/export data from a Minecraft scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to export the scoreboard data of a Minecraft world onto a string, JSON or TXT file.

I would be able to get the data from the savefile of the game but I haven't figured out where exactly is scoreboard stored.

I also tried using Minecraft Scripting API but I don't know how to access the exact scoreboard info without commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the scoreboard information in the Access database file included in your world data. This can be found at the following directory:

> USERPATH\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds\WORLD_STRING\db

Where `USERPATH` is your unique user path (typically something like `C:\Users\MyName`) and `WORLD_STRING` is your world's unique string; for example, mine was `vTJOYTT5AAA=`. Once you have this directory open, it should look *something* like this:

**[image: Screenshot of file explorer.]**

If you have Microsoft Access, you can use the file `000005` here that is of type `Microsoft Access ...`, the exact file extension is `.ldb`. However, since I don't, I'll use the `000004` text document; just keep in mind that some of the data is incomprehensible:

[image: Screenshot of the text document.]

For this answer, I created a test objective and made it's display name "*Tester*" to make it easier to find:

[image: Screenshot of the found display name.]

However, even the data surrounding it is rather incomprehensible, so I'll leave it to you to dive through the data for what you need.

---

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PHP-NBT-Decoder-Encode](https://github.com/Radon8472/PHP-NBT-Decoder-Encode) to decode the data for your scoreboard.

You will find the Scoreboard data in you worlds-folder in  `data/scoreboard.dat`.

With [PHP-NBT-Decoder-Encode](https://github.com/Radon8472/PHP-NBT-Decoder-Encode) you can open this file to get the data with php e.g. using this code:

```
<?php
  require(dirname(__FILE__)."/nbt.class.php");
  $nbt = new nbt();   
  $nbt->loadFile($inputFile); 

  // Print all data as php-array
  print_r($nbt->root);


  // Print as Json
  $output = json_encode($nbt->root, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
  echo str_replace("},", "},".PHP_EOL, $output);
?>
```